# Jenkins java process started as a defined user

Tags: java, process, jenkins

Currently I'm running Jenkins on Windows machine, The problem is that sometimes java*32.exe process is not killed after build and hangs.
I tried to use taskkill /F /IM java*32.exe to kill it before next build but it's not very effective. I think that the problem is caused by default user that starts the process which in this case is SYSTEM.

Is it possible to specify Jenkins user or windows user as a starter of the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Install Jenkins as service. Open **service**, right-click Jenkins service. Select start-up user.

From windows service documentation:

> The list of services immediately shows you some of the options that
>   you will be able to view and configure for each service. The key
>   options that you should note from the figure above is the following:
>
> - Status
> - Startup Type
> - Log On As

Comment: I'm running Jenkins as a service so I will check that and give you feedback, thank you for the tip.